# Creating secrets from env file configured to a certain namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So when creating secrets I often will use:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic super-secret --from-env-file=secrets
```

However, I wanted to move this to a dedicated secrets.yaml file, of kind "Secret" as per the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-secret-generic-em-

However, to do this, I need to base64 encode all of the secrets. Wha! This is bad imho. Why can't kubectl handle this for us? (Another debate for another day).

So, I am back to using the `kubectl create secret` command which works really well for ease of deployment - however, I am wondering what the process is to apply said creation of secret to a specific namespace? (Again, this probably would involve something tricky to get things to work - but why it's not a standard feature yet is a little worrying?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kubectl's standard options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) include a `--namespace` or `-n` option*, which can achieve this with zero fuss:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic super-secret --from-env-file=secrets --namespace=whatever_namespace_you want
```

*This is not included or mentioned in the documentation for creating a secret, explicitly. It's assumed knowledge for that section.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `stringData` section of a Secret instead of `data` section. That won't require base64 encoding. Here, is an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-basic-auth
  namespace: demo
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  username: admin
  password: t0p-Secret
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#basic-authentication-secret

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--dry-run` and `-oyaml` flags.

Use this command to generate your secrets.yaml file

```sh
kubectl create secret generic super-secret \
  --from-env-file=secrets --namespace <your-namespace> \
  --dry-run=client -oyaml > secrets.yaml
```

---

The above is pretty standard in the k8s community.